# Subquery function inside trigger when clause

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I want to create a trigger that prevents deletion of a record if student has AVG(RESULT) more than 3

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DeleteStudentResults
  BEFORE DELETE ON SESSION_RESULTS
  REFERENCING OLD AS old NEW AS new
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN ((SELECT AVG(RESULT) from session_results where STUDENT_ID = :new.STUDENT_ID)>= 3)
  BEGIN
   raise_application_error (-20100, 'You can not delete initial record');
 END;
```

[image: ER MODEL]

But Oracle says it's forbidden to have SELECT statement inside when clause.
How can I achieve such behaviour that deletion is prevented if average is more or equals than 3?

Comment: I notice that you use an :new value in a delete trigger .. the delete trigger, however, only has an :old value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take it as suggestion

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DeleteStudentResults
  BEFORE DELETE ON SESSION_RESULTS
  REFERENCING OLD AS old NEW AS new
  FOR EACH ROW
  declare 
  avg_result number;
  BEGIN
  (SELECT AVG(RESULT) into avg_result from session_results where STUDENT_ID = :old.STUDENT_ID);
  if(avg_result>=3) then
   raise_application_error (-20100, 'You can not delete initial record');
   end if;
 END;
```

Comment: It compiled succesfully, but when trying to execute `DELETE FROM SESSION_RESULTS WHERE STUDENT_ID = 24;` it says `SQL Error: ORA-04091: table ADMIN.SESSION_RESULTS is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
04091. 00000 -  "table %s.%s is mutating, trigger/function may not see it"
*Cause:    A trigger (or a user defined plsql function that is referenced in
           this statement) attempted to look at (or modify) a table that was
           in the middle of being modified by the statement which fired it.
*Action:  Rewrite the trigger (or function) so it does not read that table.`

Answer (score 1):

it is no good idea to solve this by a delete trigger

for example with session_results

```
id   studend_id   result
1    9            1
5    9            2
7    9            5
```

if you delete this student then it depends on the order the rows are processed.

```
 delete id=1  avg(1,2,5)= 2.7
 delete id=5  avg(2,5)=3.5 --> raise error
```

but

```
 delete id=7  avg(1,2,5)= 2.7
 delete id=1  avg(1,2)=1.5 
 delete id=5  avg(2)=2
```

try to solve this by materialized view, for details see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/o58asktom-101055.html